# Best practice for connect/express modules in Coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript, express

I'm writing Express.js modules in CoffeeScript, and I'm not sure of the best way to structure them.

The way I want to utilize the module is something like

**app.coffee**

```
Mailer = require('./lib/mailer')
amazon_mailer = new Mailer
  key: "somekey"
  secret: "somesecret"
  type: "SES"
...
amazon_mailer.send(...)
```

So, in Coffeescript, I'm thinking about doing it this way:

**/lib/mailer.coffee**

```
class Mailer
  constructor: (options) ->
    @options = options

  send: (...) ->
    ...

module.exports = Mailer
```

In my testing, this works, but is it the proper way to do it?  I've been unable to find any good examples about how to structure express modules in CoffeeScript.  Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: In your example, `Mailer` is just a Node module; it has nothing to do with Connect/Express.

Comment: For what it's worth, CoffeeScript has some sugar for your constructor. It can become:   constructor: (@options) ->

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach is fine. It's common to export a constructor from a Node library.

The only thing you have to worry about is exporting the `Mailer` class in such a way that it can be `require`d directly. You can do that by adding the line

```
module.exports = Mailer
```

after defining the class.

Comment: Doh, yeah, I missed that bit in my code example.  Edited my question to fix it.